# Power BI - Creating and using a variable

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm working in a demand forecast sheet, where we have a total amount of `current qty` for a given item.

We have qty sales projections for each future week, I need to take the `current qty`, store it in a variable, and subtract it from `Wk1` projected qty sales, save that variable, and then continue subtracting it from `Wk2`, `Wk3` and so on until it reaches 0. The goal is to determine how many weeks worth of stock we have before running out.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's not very elegant, but unless you are projecting out many many weeks, then you can do something like this

```
WeeksOfStock =
SWITCH(TRUE(),
       [current qty] - [wk1 sales] <= 0, 1,
       [current qty] - [wk1 sales] - [wk2 sales] <= 0, 2,
       [current qty] - [wk1 sales] - [wk2 sales] - [wk3 sales] <= 0, 3,
       ...
       --else clause--
       )
```

If you are projecting out further and this isn't feasible, then things get harder as DAX isn't really built for looping.